# python imaplib ssl proton bridge

Tags: python, ssl, imaplib

I have trying to login to my protonmail account from python via proton bridge.
The initial project is to get a count of new messages for an account.

When I try and run it from
Kernel: 5.19.0-76051900-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Cinnamon 5.2.7
Distro: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS base: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy

I receive an error

ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)

Any thoughts on what is causing the error and how to resolve it?

TIA

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                                                                                                 
import imaplib
import ssl

usern="username"
passw="password"
bridge_certificate="cert.pem"


sslctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
sslctx.options &= ~ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
sslctx.load_verify_locations(cafile=bridge_certificate)
sslctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL
sslctx.check_hostname = False

count = 0
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("localhost", 1143, ssl_context=sslctx)
imap.login(usern, passw)
imap.select('INBOX')
status, response = imap.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
if status == 'OK':
    for num in response[0].split():
        count=count+1
print(count)
imap.close()
imap.logout()
```

see the syxtax above for what I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing SSL with IMAP:

- immediate upgrade to TLS directly after the TCP connect
- TLS upgrade of a plain TCP connection after the STARTTLS command

As can be seen from [the documentation](https://proton.me/support/protonmail-bridge-clients-windows-thunderbird), proton bridge uses the second option (STARTTLS).

But `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL` uses the first option (immediate TLS after TCP connect). This means the SSL stack in Python is sending a TLS ClientHello directly after the TCP connect and is expecting a TLS ServerHello back. But - the server side (proton bridge) instead sends the plain IMAP welcome message on connect, since it is expecting TLS only after STARTTLS. This IMAP welcome message then gets misinterpreted as TLS ServerHello, which results in the `SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER` error you see.

The fix is not to use `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL` but instead `imaplib.IMAP4` together with [`starttls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.starttls), i.e. something like this:

```
imap = imaplib.IMAP4("localhost", 1143)
imap.starttls(ssl_context=sslctx)
```

Comment: Trying this syntax gives me the error below.

    map = imaplib.IMAP4("localhost", 1143)
    print(imap.welcome)
    imap.starttls(ssl_context=sslctx)
    try:
        imap.login(usern, passw)
        print("Logged in as %r !" % usern)
    except:
        imaplib.errno
        print("Log in failed.")


b'* OK [CAPABILITY IDLE IMAP4rev1 MOVE STARTTLS UIDPLUS UNSELECT] Proton Mail Bridge 03.00.21 - gluon session ID 18'
Log in failed.
imaplib.IMAP4.error: command SELECT illegal in state NONAUTH, only allowed in states AUTH, SELECTED

Comment: @atammayata: This means that the answer correctly addressed the problem you've shown in your question: SSL was successfully established here. This new error has nothing to do with your original question.  For follow-up questions please ask a new question. But in short: as you can see the login failed so you have to focus on this part, no longer on SSL.

Answer (score -1):

remove this
`sslctx.options &= ~ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3` it is not supported by ProtonMail: [Reference](https://protonmail.com/bridge/installation#authentication-and-encryption)

add `ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1` and `ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1` options to the SSLContext to disable support for TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1

Comment: That piece of code is removing SSL3 support, not adding it.